# Project loom: Why are virtual threads not the default?

Tags: java, project-loom

According to the project loom documentation virtual threads behave like normal threads while having almost zero cost and the ability to turn blocking calls into non-blocking ones.

If this is true, then why are they separate things? Why not just make them the default? Is there any reason to *not* use them?

Comment: project Loom is exactly about adding virtual threads, but it is still under active development, that is, not ready. And from an [Oracle Blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/going-inside-javas-project-loom-and-virtual-threads) about project Loom: "*Things simply are not yet at the point where meaningful comparisons can be made, and the current performance is not thought to be really indicative of the final version.*"

Answer (score 4):

There are really two questions here: 1. Why are virtual threads not the default? and 2. Is there ever a reason not to use them.

Regarding the default, Java really has not concept of a "default" thread. Once virtual threads arrive, when you create a thread, you *must* specify whether you want a platform thread or a virtual thread. The question then becomes why have we decided not to automatically replace today's threads with virtual threads (i.e. make `new Thread()` create a virtual thread). The answer to that is quite simple: it would not be helpful at all and *might* well be quite harmful. It would not be helpful because the advantages of virtual threads come from the ability to create a great many of them. If your application creates N threads today, nothing would be gained by turning those N threads into virtual threads. The scaling advantage of virtual threads would only kick in when your application creates, say, 1000N threads, which means it would need to be changed, anyway (e.g. by replacing `Executors.newFixedThreadPool` with `Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExector`). It might be harmful because while virtual threads' semantics are *almost* the same as platform threads, they are not perfectly backward compatible (see [JEP 425](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/425) for details).

As to the question about when *not* to use virtual threads, there are some obvious cases. E.g. when your threads heavily interact with native code, which knows nothing about virtual threads, or when you depend on some detail that has changed for virtual threads, like the ability to subclass `Thread`. Other cases are not so clear. For example, CPU-bound operations do not benefit from having more threads than CPU cores, so they do not benefit from the multitude of virtual threads, but that doesn't mean that they would be *harmed*. We're still not ready to say that *users* should pick virtual threads by default, but we might well get there, as we learn more about how people use them.

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that Project Loom is under active experimental development. Things may change.

---

## No default

You asked:

> Why not just make them the default?

In modern Java, we generally do not address threads directly. Instead, we use the Executors framework added years ago in Java 5.

In particular, in most cases a Java programmer uses the [`Executors`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) utility class to produce an [`ExecutorService`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). That executor service is backed by various kinds of thread factories or thread pools.

For example, if you want to serialize one task after another, we would use an [executor service backed by a single thread](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()).

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() ;
```

If you browse through `Executors` class Javadoc, you will see a variety of options.  None of them is "default". The programmer chooses one to suit the needs of her particular situation.

With [Project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main), we will have at least one more such option to choose from. In the preview build of Java, call the new [`Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/loom/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()) to get an executor service backed by [virtual threads](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/425). Go nuts, and throw a million tasks at it.

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor() ;
```

You asked:

> why are they separate things?

One of the highest priorities for the Java team is backward-compatibility: Existing apps should be able to run without surprise.

Virtual threads have a *very* different behavior and performance profile than platform threads. So I do not expect to see the Java team retrofitting virtual threads onto existing features of Java generally. They may choose to do so, but only if absolutely certain no detrimental effects will surface in the behavior of existing apps.

## When to choose or avoid virtual threads

You asked:

> Is there any reason to not use them?

Yes, certainly. Two reasons:

- CPU-bound tasks
- Tasks used to indirectly throttle other resources

### CPU-bound tasks

The entire point of virtual threads is to keep the "real" thread, the platform host-OS thread, busy. When a virtual thread blocks, such as waiting for storage I/O or waiting network I/O, the virtual thread is "dismounted" from the host thread while another virtual thread is "mounted" on the host thread to get some execution done.

So, if your task’s code does not block, do not bother with virtual threads. But this kind of code is rare. Most tasks in most apps are often waiting for users, storage, networks, attached devices, etc. An example of a rare task that might not block is something that is [CPU-bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound) like video-encoding/decoding, scientific data analysis, or some kind of intense number-crunching. Such tasks should be assigned to platform threads directly rather than virtual threads.

### Throttling

Another reason to avoid virtual threads is with existing code that depends on the limits or bottlenecks of platform threads to throttle their app’s usage of other resources. For example, if a database server is limited to 10 simultaneous connections, then some app have been written to use an executor service backed by only 8 or 9 threads. Such existing code should not be blindly switched to virtual threads.

Of course such code is less than optimal. Such a code base would be better, clearer, more obvious to comprehend if explicit limiting/throttling mechanisms were utilized.

Using explicit throttling mechanisms will be needed if a programmer wants to benefit having thousands, even millions, of simultaneous virtual threads while avoiding exhausting/overloading other limited resources.

Java has long offered such throttling mechanisms. They just were not always used, given the simplicity/ease of relying on the limits/bottlenecks of a limited number of platform threads.

---

I am no expert on this. So rely on those who *are* experts. For details and insights, be sure to read the articles and watch the presentations and interviews by Ron Pressler, Alan Bateman, or other members of the Project Loom team.

Comment: "... in most cases a Java programmer uses the `Executors` utility class": you have some evidence for this? I use both and I would not like to say which I do most. Maybe that's what *should* happen, but at present it is a mere assertion.

Comment: Like MarquisDeEJP, I also have doubts as to the veracity of that statement. But it is certainly a noble goal to use `Executors` to their fullest power. Very nicely written as usual.

Comment: Hi, what ExecutorService has to do with virtual threads ? its just an abstraction of associated thread pool, rather be virtual or not. In my opinion the question is about why they are not platform thread or what is differences.

Comment: @Lunatic I believe you need to reread my Answer. I already addressed your points.

Answer (score 1):

Lets begin with

> Why not just make them the default?

**Virtual threads are wrapped upon **platform threads**, so you may consider them an **illusion** that JVM provides, the whole idea is to make lifecycle of threads to [CPU bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound) operations.**

- Platform Threads versus Virtual threads. Platform threads take OS
  threads hostage in IO based tasks and operations limited to number of
  applicable threads with in thread pool and OS threads, by default
  they are non Daemon threads
- Virtual threads are implemented with JVM, in CPU bound operations the
  associated to platform threads and retuning them to thread pool,
  after IO bound operation finished a new thread will be called from
  thread pool, so no hostage in this case.

**Fourth level architecture to have better understanding.**

[image]

CPU

- Multicore CPU multicores with in cpu executing operations.

OS

- OS threads the OS scheduler allocating cpu time to engaged OS
  threads.

JVM

- platform threads are wrapped totally upon OS threads with both task
  operations
- virtual threads are associated to platform threads in each CPU bound
  operation, each virtual thread can be associated with multiple
  platform threads as different times.

**Virtual threads with Executer service**

- More effective to use executer service cause it associated to thread pool an limited to applicable threads with it, however in compare of virtual threads, with Executer service and virtual contained we do not ned to handle or manage the associated thread pool.

  ```
   try(ExecutorService service = Executors.newVirtualThreadPerTaskExecutor()) {
       service.submit(ExecutorServiceVirtualThread::taskOne);
       service.submit(ExecutorServiceVirtualThread::taskTwo);
   }
  ```
- Executer service implements Auto Closable interface in JDK 19, thus when used with in 'try with resource', once it reach to end of 'try' block the 'close' api being called, alternatively main thread will wait till all submitted task with their dedicated virtual threads finish their lifecycle and associated thread pool being shutdown.

  ```
   ThreadFactory factory = Thread.ofVirtual().name("user thread-", 0).factory();
   try(ExecutorService service = Executors.newThreadPerTaskExecutor(factory)) {
       service.submit(ExecutorServiceThreadFactory::taskOne);
       service.submit(ExecutorServiceThreadFactory::taskTwo);
   }
  ```
- Executer service can be created with virtual thread factory as well, just putting thread factory with it constructor argument.
- Can benefits features of Executer service like Future and Completable Future.

**Virtual threads advantages**

- exhibits exact the same behavior as platform threads.
- disposable and can be scaled to millions.
- much more lightweight than platform threads.
- fast creation time, as fast as creating string object.
- the JVM does delimited continuation on IO operations, no IO for
  virtual threads.
- yet can have the sequential code as previous but way more effective.
- the JVM gives an illusion of virtual threads, underneath whole story
  goes on platform threads.
- Just with usage of virtual thread CPU core become much more concurrent, the combination of virtual threads and multi core CPU with ComputableFutures to parallelized code is very powerful

**Virtual threads usage cautions**

- Don not use monitor i.e the synchronized block, however this will fix in new release of JDK's, an alternative to do so is to use 'ReentrantLock' with try-final statement.
- Blocking with native frames on stack, JNI's. its very rare
- Control memory per stack (reduce thread locales and no deep recursion)
- Monitoring tools not updated yet like debuggers, JConsole, VisualVM etc

Find more on [JEP-425](https://openjdk.org/jeps/425)

Answer (score 0):

If you make them default a good portion of the existing java code won't just be able to switch to java 19, because that code is optimized for OS threads.
Java **has** to be backward compatible.

There are cases where Virtual Threads don't make much sense for example

- Applications that do heavy computations
- If you make requests to a DB that has max connection pool, the bottleneck is not the threads
- Using thread locals is not a good idea with Virtual Threads

Furthermore probably most of the existing code that deals with threads pools them which again goes against the main idea